# TYPO3 v9.5.31, default language in the form text field, tt_news, in the backend panel is displayed with HTML tags

Tags: localization, typo3

My site is bilingual, French-English, TYPO3 v9.5.31. The default language is French.

When I want to add English translation to the news block (tt_news) in the backend panel, the default language is shown in the HTML tags. Only the text field is incorrect, all other fields - Header, Subheader are correct.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: I'd consider this as a feature rather than a disadvantage or bug. It  In the frontend it's not printed like this but it allows a quick overview what is really in the French language, even if links are included.

Comment: Thanks @David for the comment, I also see an advantage in this, but the editor wants the html code to be hidden. Do you know how to deactivate this display method?